# Mocking firebase's auth as object and function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, firebase, testing, mocking, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write minimalistic mocks fro firebase's auth to satisfy use cases like

```
  facebookSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await FacebookLogIn.logIn();
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(user.accessToken);
      await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert("Error", e.message);
    }
  };
```

I've got this far

```
const firebase = {
  auth: {
    onAuthStateChange: callback => {
      callback({
        user: {
          uid: "123",
          email: "test@email.com"
        }
      });
    },
    FacebookAuthProvider: {
      credential: accessToken => ({ param: "1" });
    }
  }
};
```

my main concern now is difference when doing

```
const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(user.accessToken);
```

and

```
await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
```

you can see that auth here is an object and a function at the same time, I'm not entirely sure about how I can mock that :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript functions are objects too. You can simply add the properties you need to it.

```
const firebase = {
  auth: function(){
    console.log('foo');
  }
};
firebase.auth.bar = 'bar';
firebase.auth();
console.log(firebase.auth.bar);
```